# Iterating over a list of lists and ignoring strings if they appear inside a larger string - Python

Tags: python, string, list

I want to iterate over a list of lists, and check if any of the strings in the second position are in any of the other strings in the second position. If they are, they are to be skipped over. I then only want to return the strings from the first position as a larger string. This needs to work with any strings in a list.

This description is horrific, so here is an example.

```
record = [['436', 'University'], ['123', 'University Hospital'], ['956', 'School']]
```

The output I would want here is:

```
'123 956'
```

This is because "University" is in "University Hospital", so I do not need the number associated with it.

I have had no luck coming up with a solution, and this is the best I could do:

```
final_string = ''
for inst in record:
    if inst[1] not in record:
         final_string = final_string + inst[0] + ' '
```

This returns all the strings in the first position, i.e.

```
'436 123 956 '
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could work.

```
for i, inst in enumerate(record):
    append = True
    for rec in (x[1] for x in record[i + 1:]):
        if inst[1] in rec:
            append = False
            break
    if append:
        final_string = final_string + inst[0] + ' '
```

To make some performance improvements then you can just *cache* already searched words, but that's another topic!

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

This is condensed, but it's not very efficient:

```
record = [['436', 'University'], ['123', 'University Hospital'], ['956', 'School']]

d = {k:v for (v,k) in record}
toks = [v for (k,v) in d.iteritems() if sum(1 for kk in d if k in kk) < 2]

print toks            # ['123', '956'] (as a list)
print ' '.join(toks)  # 123 956        (as a string, space separated)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going for parsimony over efficiency, this will do it in one line:

```
>>> record = [['436', 'University'], ['123', 'University Hospital'], ['956', 'School']]
>>> ' '.join(x[0] for x in record if not [x[1] in s for s in (y[1] for y in record)].count(True) > 1)
'123 956'
```